# Creating new field based on the sum of occurrences of feature attribute

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes, expression, count

I have an `"Owner_Name"` field. I want to add a virtual field `"Num_Properties"` containing the number of properties each owner owns. ().

To figure this I believe I need the expression for the `"Num_Properties"` field to count the number of occurrences of the same owner name within all the features/rows. I'm not sure what my expression needs to be. I'm assuming that I should be using `count()`.

```
count("Owner_Name", filter:= "Owner_Name" = attribute($currentfeature, 'Owner_Name'))
```

That doesn't work, just an example of what I've tried.  Apparently that elicits the same value on both sides of the "=" for the filter.

Comment: Is `count("Owner_Name", group_by:="Owner_Name")` what you are looking for?

Comment: That's the ticket!  I nearly tried that one.. somehow I missed it.  I knew it had to be simple.  Thank you so much!

Comment: @MrXsquared - from the reaction of the OP, I guess you should add it as an answer. Kaizen777: this site encourages accepting (hit the green checkbox) and/or  upvote an answer that was helpful (when it's posted as an anwer, not a comment) .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this purpose you need to use `group_by:=` instead of a `filter:=`, like:

```
count("Owner_Name", group_by:="Owner_Name")
```

This counts the number of `"Owner_Name"` in each `"Owner_Name"`-group having the same value.